# How to simulate an onKeyDown event using Jest / Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I am creating a simple calculator with Javascript/ReactHooks, which has an input box with a onKeyDown attribute:

```
// from Calculator.js, in the return statement
<input id="input" value={inputLine} type="text" onKeyDown={(i) => setInputLineFromKeydown(i)} readOnly></input>
```

The setInputLineFromKeydown function handles displaying what is typed in the input box and looks for important keys such as "Enter" or "=" (to know when to start calculating). Here is where I'm trying to test it using Jest/Enzyme:

```
// from Calculator.test.js
const wrapper = shallow(<Calculator />);
it('should be able to call setInputLineFromKeydown', () => {
    wrapper.find('input').simulate('keypress', {key: '1'});
    wrapper.find('input').simulate('keypress', {key: '+'});
    wrapper.find('input').simulate('keypress', {key: '2'});
    wrapper.find('input').simulate('keypress', {key: 'Enter'});
});
```

Although this test 'passes', I can see from my code coverage that the keys aren't being pressed (Below is code from my Calculator.js flie, test coverage shows that the line that includes "i.key === 'Enter'" is not covered)

```
// from Calculator.js
const setInputLineFromKeydown = (i) => {
        let screen = document.getElementById("input");
        i.persist();

        if (isFinite(i.key) ||
            (i.key === "+" || i.key === "-" || i.key === "*" || i.key === "/"
           || i.key === "=" || i.key === "Enter" || i.key === "c")) {

            setInputLine(inputLine + i.key);
...
}
```

Why is the simulate keypress not working properly?

Comment: did you try `wrapper.find('input').simulate('keydown', {key: '1'})`?

Comment: @strdr4605 Yes I just tried that, I switched all of the keydown simulates above to keypress, and this is also a valid test statement (there are no errors related to it), but now the line that includes ' i.key === "+" || i.key === "-" || i.key === "*" || i.key === "/" ' is not covered in my coverage report.